# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pk' Python/Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm working on a project in Django and just added a field to one of my models that saves the user who created it. I set the default value of this to 'None'. Now, whenever I try to migrate I get a value error saying "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pk'". Here's what my model looks like:

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None)
    # other fields here
```

And here's the traceback that I get when I try to run `python manage.py migrate`:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, posts, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
   Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying posts.0002_post_created_by...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
field,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
self.effective_default(field)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1956, in get_db_prep_save
return self.related_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 977, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 985, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pk'
```

Now I figure that this has something to do with the primary key of `User` but I'm not really sure how to fix it since all the lines in the traceback are in the actual Python files. Thanks for you help.

Edit: posts/migrations/0002_post_created_by.py added by request:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('posts', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='post',
            name='created_by',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=b'pk', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
     ]
```

Comment: Can you show `posts/migrations/0002_post_created_by.py`?

Comment: Is it a custom User model or the default?

Comment: It's the default User. I added `posts/migrations/0002_post_created_by.py` to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have set default to `b'pk'` before, made the migration, then changed the default to `None` and then tried to run the migration.

You need to delete the old (unapplied) migration and create a new one with when `default=None` is set.

Be aware however that `default=None` is the case anyways, and a `None` default isn't valid with `null=False` (which is implicitly set here).

Answer (score 0):

```
field=models.ForeignKey(default=b'pk', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
```

This is an invalid default value for the underlying `IntegerField` of the `ForeignKey`. You must change it to a valid integer value.